# Jenkins / Hudson CI Minimum Requirements for a linux RH installation

Tags: linux, hudson, redhat

We are planning on using [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) (used to be Hudson) for the automated builds of our project.

I need to find out what it needs from a system requirements standpoint (RAM, disk, CPU) for a Linux RH installation.

We will be testing a Mobile application project.

I did check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4899585/1015510) but couldn't find a response.

Comment: You'll need to specify some more data: 1. What's the maximum number of concurrent builds that you'd like to run ?  2. How much memory, CPU and disk does a typical build need ?  3. What's the maximum time you're prepared to wait for a build if the max. number of concurrent builds is already running ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've been maintaining a Jenkins / Sonar / Nexus and I pointed out a minimal configuration (Debian 5):

- CPU : n/a (bye bye plain old school CPU at least ;) )
- RAM : 1GB (I prefer 2)
- HDD : depends on the needs. For my use, a 8 module J2EE Maven project + db scripts (6500 lines of code) represents less of 50 MB. I configured Jenkins to store 10 builds (500 MB)

**However**, if Jenkins has to manage several projects at the time, you have to consider few things:

- keep Jenkins data in a separate directory of the system (default install may put those in `/usr`) with the Jenkins config way of your choice
- mount a dedicated HDD partition on this directory and let you a way to manage space on disk (virtual drive, partition resizing tool...)
- supervising activity to prevent space left and avoid an angry boss :) (Nagios for example)

Think about backup, other application on server, and a important thing - Jenkins resources depends on JVM capacity.