# Running Jenkins on Ubuntu VPS with low amount of RAM (256 MB)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jenkins, vps, ram

I have problems running Jenkins on my Ubuntu VPS/VServer. It seems to be obvious that the problem results from my low RAM setting (256 MB). However I'm not sure what to do next. Maybe someone can help me figuring out how to proceed best.

**Here is what happens:**

After installing Jenkins, either the Jenkins Dashboard becomes availabe at IP-ADDRESS:8080 or the Jenkins Server crashes (`$ sudo service jenkins status`
--> *"Jenkins Continuous Integration Server is not running"*).
When I'm lucky and the dashboard becomes available, all links seem to work at first, but when I click on the "Manage"-link, the Jenkins server crashes again.

When checking the Jenkins log in */var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log*, not much can be found about the reasons for the crash. I only find the following line I don't understand really as I'm not using Apache, but nginx:

> Sep 08, 2015 10:12:51 AM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
>   INFO: NO JSP Support for , did not find
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet Jenkins home directory:
>   /var/lib/jenkins found at: EnvVars.masterEnvVars.get("JENKINS_HOME")

**Now to my question:**

Do I just need to add RAM or can I maybe just add swap memory or reconfigure the Jenkins startup file? And if I should add RAM, would 1 GB be enough for the beginning as stated here: [Jenkins / Hudson CI Minimum Requirements for a linux RH installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8747533/jenkins-hudson-ci-minimum-requirements-for-a-linux-rh-installation)?

I'm just using the VPS to try out Jenkins as part of the book [Test-Driven Web Development with Python](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000000754/ch20.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no alternative to RAM except more RAM. Swap is not a replacement for RAM and is not usable like RAM.

1GB should be fine as I'm running a Jenkins on a VPS with 1GB. But it is not doing any heavy lifting there so depending on what you want to run more might be needed.

Comment: OK, thanks for your answer. Is there any logfile where I could see that it crashed because of memory shortage? I just used `$ free` and noticed that it crashed when the amount of free memory was very low.